# Mailbox get in SimGrid

Tags: c++, simgrid

I am studying mailboxes in simgrid looking at examples from the documentation, however when I try to compile the examples there are errors, mainly in mailbox-> get.
I'll put the code snippet below.

```
if (rank == 0) {
  /* The root actor (rank 0) first sends the token then waits to receive it back */
  XBT_INFO("Host \"%u\" send 'Token' to Host \"%s\"", rank, neighbor_mailbox->get_cname());
  std::string msg = "Token";
  neighbor_mailbox->put(&msg, token_size);
  const auto* res = my_mailbox->get<std::string>();
  XBT_INFO("Host \"%u\" received \"%s\"", rank, res->c_str());
} else {
  auto* res = my_mailbox->get<std::string>();
  XBT_INFO("Host \"%u\" received \"%s\"", rank, res->c_str());
  XBT_INFO("Host \"%u\" send 'Token' to Host \"%s\"", rank, neighbor_mailbox->get_cname());
  neighbor_mailbox->put(res, token_size);
}
```

the error occurs in const auto res = my_mailbox->getstd::string();

Error: *it is not possible to deduce the type 'auto'* and
*type name is not allowed*

Comment: My guess would be that `my_mailbox->get<std::string>()` doesn't return a pointer.  Are you sure it doesn't return an `std::string` by value or (`const`?) reference?

Comment: Yes it seems that the error was in the syntax after all.
I manage to fix it using `const auto *res = static_cast<std::string*>(my_mailbox->get());`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `auto* res = my_mailbox->get<std::string>();` with `const auto *res = static_cast<std::string*>(my_mailbox->get());`